# How do I remove user input from a list variable?

Tags: python-3.x, variables

If I had a variable list and wanted to remove the user input from that list, how would I go about doing so?

people = ('Jim', 'Tim', 'Kim','Ben')

print('please choose a person')

print(people)

user_name = input(#if say Kim is typed)

print('Hi', user_name,)

print('Now pick another person')

**print()<------ # print the people variable without user_name**

Answer (score 0):

Tuples are inmutable, so you must use a list instead.

So, convert the tuple to a list:

```
l = list(people)
```

Remove the desired item:

```
l.remove(user_name)
```

Print the the new list:

```
print(l)
```

Comment: Thank you so much !

Comment: If the answer was useful for you please leave your vote. I appreciate it!